# How to download golang and node in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, go

I am building a simple node server to run in docker. I have introduced a small golang module that can be executed by running

```sh
go run /root/component-review-handler/downloader/main.go -build 1621568 -outdir /usr
```

I am currently running this locally in my node server by running the follow script on startup

```js
exec(
    `cd ${process.env.ROOT_PATH}/component-review-handler && go run cmd/downloader/main.go`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        logger.error(`error: ${error.message}`)
        return
      }
      if (stderr) {
        logger.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
        return
      }
      logger.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    }
  )
```

But When I run the code in docker, I get the following error

```sh
error: Command failed: cd /usr/src/app/component-review-handler && go run cmd/downloader/main.go

/bin/sh: 1: go: not found
```

Does anyone know how I can install both node and golang in my docker container?
Current Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js" ]
```

Comment: the same way you would install them in any other system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go is a compiled language, and you shouldn't usually need the Go toolchain just to run a Go program.

I'd use a multi-stage build for this.  The first stage is `FROM golang` to have the toolchain and build the binary; the second `COPY --from` the first image into a directory that's normally on the search path.

```sh
FROM golang:1.17 AS downloader
WORKDIR /app                       # not under /go
COPY component-review-handler/ ./  # (double-check this COPY syntax)
RUN go build -o downloader ./cmd/downloader

FROM node:14
# vvv add this line
COPY --from=downloader /app/downloader /usr/local/bin/

# same as before
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Since the binary is now in `/usr/local/bin` which is a default `$PATH` directory, in your code you can just run it, without the `cd` or `go run` parts

```js
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
execFile('downloader',
         (error, stdout, stderr) => { ... });
```

Comment: This looks like its working! Thanks so much! Do you know how I could add arguments to the go command? For example, if my script looked like this


go run /root/component-review-handler/downloader/main.go -build 1621568 -outdir /usr

Comment: [`execFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processexecfilefile-args-options-callback) takes an array of additional arguments; `execFile('downloader', ['-build', '1621568', '-outdir', '/usr'], callback);`

Comment: Beautiful thank you!